# SwiftUI Breaking line in UITextView wrapped by UIViewRepresentable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm struggling for breaking line in CustomUITextView. Please help...

I made CustomUITextView like below.

```swift
struct CustomTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTextView>) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.textColor = UIColor.black
        textView.font = UIFont(name: "ArialMT", size: 20)
        // textView.text = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        return textView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {  }
}
```

Then using it like this.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            CustomTextView()
                .frame(width:300, height: 300, alignment: .topLeading)
                .border(Color.red, width: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

By keyboard input it works and lines are returned at red border.

[image]

But when I take away this comment in CustomUITextView

```
textView.text = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

It will be like this and doesn't break.

[image]

Is it possible to break line when I put Strings directly from code like above too ?

Does anyone know the solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decrease compression resistance priority

[image: demo]

```
textView.font = UIFont(name: "ArialMT", size: 20)
textView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
textView.text = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
return textView
```