# SwiftUI: UITextView text does not wrap when inside a ForEach/LazyVGrid (Self-sizing/Dynamic height UITextView)

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, swiftui-list

### The issue

What I'm creating is a LazyVGrid with many UITextView as "cells" inside, but the text does not wrap when it exceeds the parent width.

When the text is a single line, all is fine:

[image: Single line text]

But when the text reaches the limit, something weird happens:

[image: Multiline text]

What **I want to achieve is simply that the text wraps**, can anyone help me?

### The code

To have  more flexibility, I chose to use a UIKit UITextView created using the UIViewRepresentable protocol, rather than using the new TextEditor provided by SwiftUI:

```
struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding private var text: String

    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        self._text = text
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.backgroundColor = .systemIndigo // debug
        return textView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        context.coordinator.parent = self
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
 
    // MARK: - Coordinator

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var parent: TextView
    
        init(_ parent: TextView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            parent.text = textView.text
        }
    }
}
```

This is my SwiftUI View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible(), spacing: 0.0), count: 1)

    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: ContentViewModel

    init(viewModel: ContentViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                ForEach($viewModel.blocks) { $block in
                    TextView(text: $block.content)
                        .frame(minHeight: 24.0)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 24.0)
        }
    }
}
```

I'll skip the ViewModel part because it's not relevant.

I've already seen and tried this [Dynamic row hight containing TextEditor inside a List in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620613/dynamic-row-hight-containing-texteditor-inside-a-list-in-swiftui/62621521#62621521), without success

Thanks everyone in advance ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62621521/12299030?

Comment: Thanks @Asperi, but I already tried it without success.

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/64966766/12299030.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi, just tried it, and actually, the text no longer expands in width in that weird way but the height does not scale up properly. 

If I enable scrolling, the text wraps correctly but the UITextView height is always fixed.